# Error when authenticate MusicKit instance

Tags: javascript, apple-musickit, apple-musickit-js

whenever I try to authenticate a MusicKit instance the popup alway shows 'Problem Connecting There may be a network issue. '. When reloading the popup it shows the login screen, but after I did log in it shows the same error page again.

On the first error screen I get the following error in the console. A searching for the error it seems to be connect to ember js.

> Error while processing route: woa Failed to construct 'URL': Invalid URL TypeError: Failed to construct 'URL': Invalid URL

> TypeError: Failed to construct 'URL': Invalid URL

On the second error page I find the following error in the console:

> Error while processing route: oauth-screen

This happens both on Brave and Safari.

Is this a bug or did i something wrong?

#### My Code:

```html
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://js-cdn.music.apple.com/musickit/v1/musickit.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener('musickitloaded', function () {
            MusicKit.configure({
                developerToken: 'My token',
                debug: true,
                suppressErrorDialog: false
            });

            let music = MusicKit.getInstance();

            music.authorize().then(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your code looks fine.  Note though that there is a new version of the SDK.  It's poorly documented, but you can find it here:  https://js-cdn.music.apple.com/musickit/v3/docs/index.html?path=/story/introduction--page

Comment: Thank you for the link. I tried the newer version, but it is still the same result. I'm currently in contact with Apple's support about this problem and I will give an update as soon as there is any development there.

Comment: @CptCookie any chance this has been resolved? My app suddenly stopped working after 3 years..

Comment: @zerohedge, for me it was a problem with how I opened the code locally. I assume this is not so helpful for something I presume to be an app in production. Sry, but the apple support was very helpful but also kind of slow in its responses.

Answer (score 0):

The Code is fine, but I opened it directly from disk. For an unknown reason, musickit does not like this. It needed to be served via a small HTTP server to work properly.

Comment: the answer is unclear